# How to make the ambience of a Dialog transparent

Tags: android, dialog

I want to use a Dialog for the pause screen of my game. But the dialog always shades the subjacent Activity (the ambience around the dialog). How can I avoid this effect?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik `Dialog`s in Android have that default behavior and it cannot be changed. For your requirement you should use something like a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). [This](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html) and [this](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/) are the links to tutorials that can help you get started.